# IE9 Dropdown menu - Filter bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter, html-lists

I have a dropdown menu which works fine in all modern browsers, but there are some weird things happening in **IE9**. The dropdown appears transparent or invisible in some way, but its box-shadow is visible. In addition, hovering fails when you mouse off the parent list item.

I am referring to the main navigation bar at the top:

http://gratefulglass.viussandbox.co/

I placed a red border on the submenu's containing element, to illustrate that the menu appears to be positioned correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: This question and the selected answer helped me today. I'm experiencing the same issue. Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `filter` CSS properties you're setting on the `<ul>` and `<a>` tags in your code. IE9 will render the gradient backgrounds for you, but that causes it to set the hasLayout flag on the element internally, which causes the renderer to treat that element as if it had `overflow: hidden;` and you can't override that by simply setting `overflow: visible;` as it's not **actually** a CSS rule, but rather the way the internal rendering engine will treat the element when processing it. If you remove the filters with `filter: none;` in an override, or simply don't set them, then you should see everything work correctly again.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for pointing this out, I never would have found this. I was about to jump out a window and give up.

Answer (score 0):

Check this links:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576568/ie-opacity-hover-sometimes),
[2](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/) 
Sorry, but cant put more links:
http://  &&  joseph.randomnetworks.com/2006/08/16/css-opacity-in-internet-explorer-ie/
http://  &&  www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?163100-Opacity-hover-not-working-in-IE

Some properties behave different or are not persistent depending the browser.
But there is always a way to make it work.
Best way to make it work, javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, I don't actually think its an opacity issue, which is why I'm so perplexed about it. The menu appearing is controlled by changing the position from left:-999em; to left: 0;

Comment: I cant see details on the error because I dont have the code but you can:
Open with IE9, press F12 and go to Script, reload de web.
I can catch some error from here but since I dont have the scripts I cant see the code where the error occurrs.
You can check the errors there, I just see that there are CSS issues.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The only errors on the page are a fontface issue, where it doesn't recognize .eot files. The font is being loaded fine anyway, so this is not the issue. There are not any actual "errors" associated with the problem I'm having.

Comment: Have you tried the compatibility view of IE9?
Can you put the code of the menu and the css please?